# Add select option by using <a> in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

How can I add more select option in AngularJS example like this:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <label>Student Class:</label>
    <select id="class" name="class">
      <option>C1608G</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" id="add" style="color: blue;">Add class</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either attributes/directives:

- **ng-options** in your select element
- **ng-repeat** in your option element

Here's an example(suppose that you have an array of objects names 'options' in your $scope):

```
<select id="class" name="class" ng-options="option as option.name for option in options track by option.value">
</select>

<select id="class" name="class">
  <option ng-repeat="option in options">
     <a href="option.address">{{option.name}}</a>
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: but how could connect with <a>? And could y write angularJs code pls, i just a newbie so i don't know much about this, sorry @mindthefrequency

Comment: in the second provided example, you cann add whatever markup you wish inside the option element.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! But how about angularJS code in script